# XML Not Well Formed Error on Server

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript

Does anyone know why I would be getting this http://briannechavis.com/mp3Player.xml

I am at a lost as to whats happening.. the xml file loads fine locally, but it will not load when i upload it to the server... then when i go directly to the link above, i see what you will see when you click on it...

heres what the xml file contains

```
<music autoPlay="true" autoNextSong="true">
<song>
    <title><![CDATA[On The Floor feat. Pitbull - JLo]]></title>
    <mp3File><![CDATA[music/1.mp3]]></mp3File>
</song>
<song>
    <title><![CDATA[Suéltate - Tito El Bambino - El Patrón]]></title>
    <mp3File><![CDATA[music/2.mp3]]></mp3File>
</song>
<song>
    <title><![CDATA[Judas - Lady Gaga]]></title>
    <mp3File><![CDATA[music/3.mp3]]></mp3File>
</song>
    <song>
    <title><![CDATA[Dont Turn Back - Colby Odonis]]></title>
    <mp3File><![CDATA[music/4.mp3]]></mp3File>
</song>
<song>
    <title><![CDATA[Whats My Name feat Drake - Rihanna]]></title>
    <mp3File><![CDATA[music/5.mp3]]></mp3File>
</song>
<song>
    <title><![CDATA[Goapele - Closer]]></title>
    <mp3File><![CDATA[music/6.mp3]]></mp3File>
</song>
```

Comment: this is a similar file and it comes up fine :/ could it be the server? http://0.s3.envato.com/files/42671/mp3Player.xml

Comment: I tried copying and pasting this text into a notepad file and the characters using the accents are coming through as chinese I believe.  Is it okay when you remove these characters? just trying to narrow it down some.

Comment: OK SOLVED! PARTLY THE EDITOR I WAS USING.. I COPIED & PASTE IN NOTEPAD AND IT POINTED OUT THE ERROR IMMEDIATELY.. :) THANKS FOR ALL THE HELP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The similar XML file you linked to has ISO-8859 encoding.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

You probably should be using UTF-8, especially if you're going to use any funky characters:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```